# $A$ and $A'$ have the same eigenvectors: Flaw in the proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, solution-verification, fake-proofs

Consider the  equation

$$Ax=\lambda x$$
where $x$ is non zero. Then, we have:
$$x'Ax=\lambda x'x$$

$$(x'Ax)'=x'A'x=(\lambda x'x)'=\lambda x'x$$
$$x'(A'x-\lambda x)=0$$
$$A'x=\lambda x$$ (since $x'$ is not zero).

Hence, this proves that A and A' have the same eigenvalues and the same **eigenvectors as well**.

However, my professor claims that in general, A and A' do **not** have the same eigenvectors.

What exactly then, is the flaw in my proof?

Comment: Two non-zero matrices may multiply to give zero matrix

Comment: Put another way, all you have shown is that the vector $x’$  is perpendicular to $A’x - \lambda x$. This is true in general as you have shown. (In general this is very intuitive because $A’lambda - I$ must be rank-deficient, because $A$ and $A’$ share the same eigenvalues. But this does not mean they share the same *eigenvectors*.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot deduce from the fact that $x'$ is not $0$ together with $x'(A'x-\lambda x)=0$ that $A'x-\lambda x=0$. For instance, if $A$ is a $2\times2$ matrix, if $x'=(1,0)$ and if $A'x-\lambda x=(0,1)$, then $x'(A'x-\lambda x)=0$, but $A'x-\lambda x\ne0$.